# Problems installing SFML on MacOS/Xcode (M2 chip)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, frameworks, sfml

I'm having problems installing SFML to macOS Sonoma 14.4 and Xcode 15.1 (M2 chip). I followed the guide on the SFML page here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-osx.php. I chose the Frameworks way because it is recommended and I copied all the files. After I created the SFML App on the last step, I cannot get it to run.

I used xcode-select --install to install CLT in Xcode like it said in the guide.
framworks and extlib is copied here:[frameworks folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwSIO.png)
Templates is copied here: [Templates folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McHVo.png)

This is the error message:
[PhaseScriptExecution failed with a non zero exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4gpj.png)
I searched online and some tutorials tell me to check this box:
[run script for install builds only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfBPa.jpg)
The error message is gone.
Then I run the program but it return this error message:[Xcode cannot find some files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9WU1.jpg)
I cannot find anything online that solve my issues and I do not understand what is going on.

Is there any way I can get this to work?